# Module parse failed: Unexpected token NextJS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

When I run "Yarn dev" this error is occurred.

I tried to fix this error so many times but it failed. I added some loaders at webpack but it's not working.

Please let me know what should I do.

This is error message:

```
error - ./node_modules/@saberhq/token-utils/dist/esm/common.js 7:9
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { Keypair, PublicKey, SystemProgram, Transaction, } from "@solana/web3.js";
| import { deserializeAccount, deserializeMint, MintLayout, Token } from ".";
> export * as token from "./token";
| /**
|  * Default number of decimals of a token.
ReferenceError: React is not defined
```

This is my webpack:

```
webpack: (config) => {
 config.node = {
  fs: 'empty'
 };

 config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(eot|woff|pdf|woff2|ogg|mp3|wav|ttf|otf|ico|mpe?g)$/i,
  loader: "file-loader",
  options: {
    name: "[path][name].[ext]",
  },
 });

 config.module.rules.push({
  include: /node_modules/,
  test: /\.mjs$/,
  type: 'javascript/auto'
 });

 config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
  loader: 'babel-loader',
  options: { presets: ['@babel/env','@babel/preset-react'] },
 });


 config.module.rules.unshift({
  test: /pdf\.worker\.(min\.)?js/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        name: "[contenthash].[ext]",
        publicPath: "_next/static/worker",
        outputPath: "static/worker"
      }
    }
  ]
 });

 if (config.module.css) {
  config.module.css.config.plugins.push(
    new FilterWarningsPlugin({
      exclude: /mini-css-extract-plugin[^]*Conflicting order between:/,
    })
  );
 }

 return config;
},
```

Please help me

Thanks

Comment: Ever figure this one out? Having a similar issue